# How to find HTML Webpage elements in the Source page

Tags: html, dom

I am looking for some way on how to view source of some elements in the webpage https://www.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/get_quote/GetQuote.jsp?symbol=ITC&illiquid=0&smeFlag=0&itpFlag=0

In that page, under the tab `Company Information`, we have `Company Announcements` like *Press Release*, *Allotment of ESOP/ESPS* etc. Under each of these headers, there are more information provided. However when I look into the Source-page, I dont see those information.

Any idea on how to find those information in the source-page.

Thanks for any pointer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are siblings of the title, not children.

```
<h3 class="alt active">
  <span id="ca21">Allotment of ESOP/ESPS</span>
  <span class="date" id="ca22">26-Oct-2018</span>
</h3>
<div class="alt" id="ca23" style="display: block;">ITC Limited has informed the Exchange regarding allotment of  986060 Equity Shares under ESOP</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, can you elaborate a little bit more

Comment: If you were looking inside of the <h3> tags where the <span> tags are, you would not have found it (that would be a child).  Instead, it was adjacent to the <h3> tag (that is a sibling).  The logical way to do this if it was built as a DOM would have been to wrap it all in a single <div> tag per line item or something like that, but this was likely just hand coded this way so it's just a big long list of sibling elements with very little organization.